# Angular7 Lifecycle Hooks and Routing

Tags: angular, angular7

I am just curious which lifecycle hooks are called when we use router.navigate in our current page, lets say for reloading the page.

```
constructor(private router: Router) { }
reload () {
    this.router.navigate(['/currentpage']);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here is the sequence

- constructor
- ngOnChanges
- ngOnInit
- ngDoCheck
- ngOnDestroy
- ngAfterContentInit
- ngAfterContentChecked
- ngAfterViewInit
- ngAfterViewChecked

Router events that allow you to track the lifecycle of the router. The sequence of router events is as follows:

- NavigationStart
- RouteConfigLoadStart
- RouteConfigLoadEnd
- RoutesRecognized
- GuardsCheckStart
- ChildActivationStart
- ActivationStart
- GuardsCheckEnd
- ResolveStart
- ResolveEnd
- ActivationEnd
- ChildActivationEnd
- NavigationEnd
- NavigationCancel
- NavigationError
- Scroll

Answer (score 1):

While using 
`this.router.navigate(['/currentpage']);`
on `/currentpage` only **AfterViewChecked** is triggered.